# при скачивании xml в строку из интернета, скачивается не полностью

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String text ="";
BufferedReader in;

URL link;
try
{
    link = new URL("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=нюша&track=только");
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line);
    }


}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

блок `album` пропускает полностью, и в `artist` тег `mbid`, не могу понять почему

Comment: Да вроде все на месте, если в вашем коде `reader` в условии цикла заменить на `in`.

Comment: Считывает он в любом случае всё, что может считать, скорее всего проблема в том, что вся страничка это не только чистый XML, вполне вероятно, что есть JS скрипты, которые подкачивают элементы в страницу

Comment: А кодировать кто русские буквы в запросе будет? То что браузер такой запрос "прожевывает", совсем не значит что можно его просто так скопировать в исходники и все.